# Sort tuple in tuple by upper and lower case

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, tuples

**Hello!**
I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
tup = ((3,'Ne'),(7,'yo'),(1,'Hey'),(3,'ne'),(7,'Yo'),(1,'hey'))
```

and im using this to sort it by abc..:

```
sorted(tup, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

the problem is that it outupt this:

```
>>> print tup
>>> ((1,'Hey'),(3,'Ne'),(7,'Yo'),(1,'hey'),(3,'ne'),(7,'yo'))
```

Instead of this (this is what i want to output):

```
>>> print tup
>>> ((1,'Hey'),(1,'hey'),(3,'Ne'),(3,'ne'),(7,'Yo'),(7,'yo'))
```

I googled, and found how to do this with `list` object, but it dont works with tuples.

Solution for `tuple` would be appreciated. **Thanks!**

Comment: Many things that work with `list` will also work with `tuple`. Please link the solution you found or show it here.

Comment: Please post your actual code. Your `tup` is syntactically incorrect

Comment: What should happen in the case of `(1, 'Hey'), (1, 'hEy'))`? Basically, do you care whether the capitalized version comes before the lowercase version?

Comment: @user3611091 your accepted  answer does not answer  your question as posted, it puts `yo` before `Yo`

Comment: @merlin2011 it didnt worked. i looked at all the solutions before posting this question :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Fixed, thanks. Thats all my code, it's a really simple regex script. Also, i your case i except that (1, 'hEy') will be first. Thank u :)

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham right! the actual list is a big list (1000+ items) so i didnt saw that. Thanks. other answer would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I have already answered

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant

```
tup = ((3,'Ne'),(7,'yo'),(1,'Hey'),(3,'ne'),(7,'Yo'),(1,'hey'))
```

And needed

```
sorted(tup, key=lambda tup: tup[1].upper())
```

Comment: THANKS!! working great!, and also the most simple solution here. :)

Comment: Just curious, how does this solution guarantee that the capital version will always appear first?

Comment: `sorted(tup, key=lambda tup: (tup[1].upper(), tup[1][0].islower()))` should fix the last two elements issue by sorting lowercase versions later.

Comment: You are right, I did not consider dictionary sorting vs. collapsing case. I see that others corrected this, as this was not really correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sorted(tup, key=lambda x: (x[1].upper(),ord(x[1][0])))

In [2]: tup = ((3,'Ne'),(7,'yo'),(1,'Hey'),(3,'ne'),(7,'Yo'),(1,'hey'))

In [3]: sorted(tup, key=lambda x: (x[1].upper(),ord(x[1][0])))
Out[3]: [(1, 'Hey'), (1, 'hey'), (3, 'Ne'), (3, 'ne'), (7, 'Yo'), (7, 'yo')]
```

Sort with sorted and settle ties with the `ord` of the first `char` of your tuple strings

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done specifying a comparison function instead of a key.

```
tup = ((3,'Ne'),(7,'yo'),(1,'Hey'),(3,'ne'),(7,'Yo'),(1,'hey'))

def compare(item1, item2):
    if item1[1].lower() < item2[1].lower():
       return -1
    elif item1[1].lower() > item2[1].lower():
       return 1
    else: 
       return -1 if item1[1] < item2[1] else 1

tup = sorted(tup, cmp=compare)
print(tup)
```